# non-flash swf on iphone

Tags: ios, ios4, flash

I want to display a list of swfs and allow the user to click on one and have it display. I wanted to use PDF, but need a little more interaction for the user. I've searched around for some swf -> iphone converters, but I want to just display the swf as PART of an app.

Any recommendations?

Comment: As I understand it, .swf is an open file type (meaning you can reach in and grab data out of it). If there is a better approach, I'm all ears. FYI adobe has two projects that I know of that use the swf format in iOS. One is Flash (render to iphone) and the other is Adobe Publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible via CS5->IOS export. It's not the most smooth, but it will allow you to load external swfs. The only gotcya is that the external swfs cannot contain any actionscript (bummer).

[Here's a simple example of flash to ios](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/iphone/).

Answer (score 0):

SWF used to be short for [Shockwave/Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF). It is not an "open" file type and requires a huge framework to work correctly, one of which is support for ActionScript. There doesn't seem to be such a framework right now, even [Skyfire](http://www.skyfire.com/) doesn't do the rendering natively but tries to convert it through a server.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf.html

"The SWF file format is available as an open specification" -- regardless it sounds like getting swf to play at any level in iOS is going to be rough :(